# Power BI Matrix Table - Sort by Date/Sum Column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Matrix table that shows a two week week over week sales total, with a grand total column. I can sort by the grand total column, but I would like to sort by the most current date column.

[image]

[image]

When I updated the filter to only show one week, it will filter properly, but when multiple weeks are present it will only sort by the total.